# Insufferable word wrap in Visual Studio XAML editor - is there any relief for 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml, visual-studio-2010

Just curious if the XAML editor is any better at auto-formatting and wrapping attributes in Visual Studio 2010.

**Here's how the editor auto wraps attributes in VS 2008:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"
Text="Current User:" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="_usersComboBox" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="200"
ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedValuePath="Name"
SelectedValue="System Administration">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
```

**Here's how I'd like the editor to auto wrap attributes:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="Current User:" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="_usersComboBox" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="200"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedValuePath="Name"
            SelectedValue="System Administration">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
```

**Does VS 2010 grant my wish?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  You should open up a Connect for that:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=3783&FeedbackType=2

May not make it until SP1, but I've found them pretty responsive to suggestions during the B2 cycle.  You might be surprised....

Comment: Done: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=523960#details

Answer (score 8):

There's something close to that.

The new editor in VS2010 supports an [`auto-indent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.wordwrapstyles(VS.100).aspx) word wrap mode.  There is no way to activate it within the product, but a PM on our team wrote a quick extension that enables that mode.  You can [download it from the VS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ac95f80f-6cfd-4b67-b0fd-e9c5c8fb27de), or download it from the extension manager in VS2010 by searching for it by name ("word wrap" should be enough) or searching for Brittany Behrens, who wrote the extension.

Comment: Thanks, Noah. I don't have VS 2010 yet, but I will definitely try this when I get it.

Comment: Just why this requires an add-on, instead of being the default, is totally inexplicable.

Comment: @romkyns - Among other reasons, (1) it doesn't do what the poster was asking (indent an extra level), (2) was generally experimental and untested, and (3) there would have been a cost to doing it, so some other feature or bug fixes would have had to drop off.

Comment: Without this behaviour, the Word Wrap feature itself could as well be dropped; it’s essentially useless. Implementing Word Wrap but not this is a bit of a waste of time.

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to install in VS 2010 Express. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech - extensions aren't supported on express editions of VS.

Answer (score 3):

I've only just found this question, after having already put up a [request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2262548-provide-virtual-formatting-in-editors-for-xaml-ra) on the VS 2010 suggestions forum.

[This video](http://youtu.be/ItapXmiuSrE?hd=1) (the first 20 secs should do it) shows XAML being reformatted *continuously* whilst it's edited with no user intervention - the XAML simply 'reflows' during typing, drag'n drop etc.

My suggestion goes a bit further because I propose fully automated 'virtual formatting', using margins instead of tabs/spaces, this means word-wrap will always work just like in a word processor. A sample screenshot shows this - leading whitespace characters (with a yellow background) are only present within an xml:space preserve block:

[image]

Word-wrap and formatting is quite complex - there are a few things going on in the screenshot:

1. The RTF includes hanging-indent formatting for element or attribute content, so wrapped text will have extra indentation - to make it clear that it's wrapped (see the wrapped *entation* value and *margin* and *width* attributes)
2. All attributes are aligned under one another
3. If an attribute value has line-feeds, new lines will be aligned with the first line.
4. Required whitespace in preformatted text is preserved whilst still keeping indentation intact.
5. [Important] All formatting is done at the same time as syntax-coloring, based on the position of line-feeds in the XAML context. Word-wrap just works like a word-processor because of the indent data carried within the line-feeds.

If this can't be done for Visual Studio, then perhaps we could see this first in [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/)?.

Comment: That would definitely be nice. +1.